# java applications monitoring tool

Tags: java, shell, health-monitoring, health-check, network-monitoring

We have a micro service architecture java applications. There are scenarios where our java application services stops running or gets killed or hung due to various reasons like server reboot or thread issues or space issues on server.

We want to have a monitoring tool(which can run without internet) which can check the health of java services on timely basis and if the services are stopped and it can alert the users through mail/messages and restart the same.

Note: Currently we are doing this by creating a shell script which executes the healthcheck api of each services. If the response is not received it calls another java service(Communication service) and triggers the mail/message api to alert the users. But this whole monitoring script goes for a toss if our communication services itself goes down.
We are looking for some much better way to do it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at prometheus. We use it extensively, with our microservices setup to output some metrics, using annotations in Spring Boot.

Comment: @Muddassir If you are hosted on AWS, you can make use of AWS Event Bridge. Through EventBridge, you can configure a rule to invoke a lambda on scheduled intervals. The lambda can invoke your APIs and send email if your health check fails.

Comment: @Sreek521 No! we are not on AWS